# Fetch data from XML in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsp

I want to fetch data from XML file in my jsp. I am using jquery in this jsp, so i am not finding any way to fetch data from XMl. Someone told me to make a different jsp which fetch data from XML and then use that data in my main jsp but how can i do this please suggest. Or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Is there any way do this by jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this shouldn't be that messy: if the file is directly accessible (not inside WEB-INF) you should be able to do something very similar to what's described [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/).

Comment: jsp is in the path "webProject/webcontent/temlates/store/SearchResult.jsp" and xml is in path "/webProject/webcontent/WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml" then what should be my url value if i do it using jquery's $.ajax({ function.